# Create a copy of a PDF file(with custom font) from another PDF file in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm not familiar with the PDF specification at all. I have a requirement where I need to generate a PDF file with custom font from another PDF file.

I tried iText I'm able to copy the pdf file but font is not embedding new file is also opening with same font..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"generate a PDF file with custom font from another PDF file"* - you mean like regular file copying?

Comment: @mkl "you mean like regular file copying?" - yes, but destination file should embed the custom(new) font.